# How can I estimate the space complexity of a class?

Tags: class, oop, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I know what is the space complexity of a function, but never heared of the space complexity of a class, does it mean the space that can be occupied by it's attributs ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist. But I find your question really interesting. Then I will try to give a possible answer that others can complete or disagree with.

I want to begin by a definition to keep things concrete. Let's talk about Java for example. According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp) Everything in Java is associated with classes and objects, along with its attributes and methods. For example: in real life, a car is an object. The car has ***attributes***, such as **weight** and **color**, and ***methods***, such as **drive** and **brake**.
So to study the class space complexity you need to study the complexity of each those things IMO:

- Class attribute spatial complexity

  In our case: **weight** and **color**
- Class method spatial complexity

  In our example: **drive** and **brake**

But it is more subtile than that you should think about **inheritance**. Our car could extend a **Vehicle** class why not. You should think about **composition** too. Our class can have more complexes attributes like **Engine**.
That is a general idea I hope it can help.